# Настройка Linux

Tags: linux, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На папке `plugins` стоят владелец/группа 0 0
На остальных файлах 1001 1001
Из-за этого не могу ничего редактировать через FTP
Как поменять на 1001 на `plugins` и что это вообще значит?

Comment: Поменять пользователя и группу теоретически можно в Filezilla или WinSCP. Но у вас ничего не выйдет. 0 0 - это root, вряд ли вы под ним работаете. Обратитесь к хостеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> владелец/группа 0 0

Означает, что владельцем этой папки является root (uid = 0) и группа root (gid = 0)

> На остальных файлах 1001 1001

Это uid первого пользователя, зарегистрированного в системе после её установки

> Как поменять на 1001 на plugins

Поскольку хозяин папки *root*, то отобрать у него эту папку может только сам *root*. Для того, что бы "прикинуться" *root*-ом существует команда  *sudo*.

Что бы сменить владельца файла существует команда *chown*. Суммируя, нужно выполнить команду:

```
sudo chown 1001:1001 plugins
```

Comment: chowN ? (8simbols)

Comment: Виноват - опечатка!